# Wordpress incorrectly serving page with content type plain/text

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have a wordpress site that I host my blog on. Recently, without any (conscious) change to the configuration I started hitting issues where the main index page was being served with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain` rather than the correct `text/html` - leading to visitors seeing the source code, rather than the rendered page.

I'm using the W3TC Browser Cache plugin and narrowed down the problem to this portion of `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.4) [NC]
  RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
  RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```

If I remove this section from the `.htaccess` file, that page loads fine, with the correct `Content-Type`. However W3TC likes to reinstate this block some time after I remove it, and the problem returns.

Comment: Does Wordpress Super Cache give you the same issues?

Comment: I've switched to Super Cache (using PHP caching to avoid touching th .htaccess) and so far so good. Thanks